# If X be a compact space and x be a non isolated point of X then X-{x} is locally compact

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering if someone can please help me with this problem that if we remove a non isolated point from a compact set then it will become a locally compact space 
would you give me a hint with this question

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: yes X is hausdorff

Comment: Is it true that if i consider X as a normal space then even for any closed set F in X the set X-F is locally compact

Comment: since if x belongs to X-F then there exist two distinct open sets U and V  in X contain x and F respectively and since U is an open set in X beside F does not intersect with U also its closure is compact in X and so it is compact in X-F . so I found an open set U in X-F contain x and its closure is compact in X-F

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $\{x\}$ is closed, so given $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, there exist disjoint open sets $U,V\subset X$ such that $y\in U$ and $\{x\}\subset V$. Then $X\setminus V$ is closed and so is a compact neighborhood of $y$ in $X\setminus\{x\}$.